# How to config maven when installing hoop

Tags: maven, configuration, hadoop, installation

I'm trying to build install hoop in ubuntu 12.04 following http://cloudera.github.com/hoop/docs/latest/ServerSetup.html, however, the problem came when the I was doing `mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true site assembly:single`, the default configuration of hoop is post bellow,

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cloudera.hoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hoop-main</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Hoop Main</description>
  <name>Hoop Main</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <url>http://github.com/cloudera/hoop</url>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <organization>
    <name>Cloudera</name>
    <url>http://www.cloudera.com</url>
  </organization>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:cloudera/hoop.git</connection>
    <url>https://github.com/cloudera/hoop</url>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>cdh.releases.repo</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
      <name>CDH Releases Repository</name>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>cdh.snapshots.repo</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <name>CDH Snapshots Repository</name>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <modules>
    <module>hoop-project</module>
    <module>hoop-testng</module>
    <module>hoop-server</module>
    <module>hoop-client</module>
    <module>hoop-webapp</module>
    <module>hoop-docs</module>
    <module>hoop-distro</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
          <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.7</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireMavenVersion>
              <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
            </requireMavenVersion>
            <requireJavaVersion>
              <version>1.6</version>
            </requireJavaVersion>
            <requireOS>
              <family>unix</family>
            </requireOS>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>clean</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-clean</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>site</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-site</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>post-site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <attach>false</attach>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>maven/assembly-empty.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

and the output is paste bellow,

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Hoop Project POM
[INFO] Hoop TestNG
[INFO] Hoop Server
[INFO] Hoop WebApp
[INFO] Hoop Client
[INFO] Hoop Docs
[INFO] Hoop Distro
[INFO] Hoop Main
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hoop Project POM 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (clean) @ hoop-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ hoop-project ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-project/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (default) @ hoop-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (site) @ hoop-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ hoop-project ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://github.com/cloudera/hoop
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-3:single (default-cli) @ hoop-project ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: maven/assembly-empty.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hoop TestNG 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-testng/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /home/pc/hoop/hoop-testng/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pc/hoop/hoop-testng/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.6:test (default-test) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-testng/target/hoop-testng-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://github.com/cloudera/hoop/hoop-testng
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-3:single (default-cli) @ hoop-testng ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: maven/assembly-empty.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hoop Server 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Compiling 79 source files to /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.6:test (default-test) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/target/hoop-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://github.com/cloudera/hoop/hoop-server
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[WARNING] The repository url 'http://repository.codehaus.org/' is invalid - Repository 'Codehaus repository' will be blacklisted.
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ hoop-server >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ hoop-server <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] The goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc' has not be previously called for the project: 'com.cloudera.hoop:hoop-testng:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'. Trying to invoke it...
[INFO] The goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc' has not be previously called for the project: 'com.cloudera.hoop:hoop-docs:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'. Trying to invoke it...
[ERROR] MavenInvocationException: Error when invoking Maven, consult the invoker log file: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/target/invoker/maven-javadoc-plugin1321551293.txt
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-docs/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-distro/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[INFO] 
5 warnings
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/src/main/java/com/cloudera/lib/server/Server.java:684: warning - @return tag has no arguments.
[WARNING] /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/src/main/java/com/cloudera/lib/server/Server.java:256: warning - Tag @link: can't find serverStatusChange(Status, Status) in com.cloudera.lib.server.Service
[WARNING] /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/src/main/java/com/cloudera/lib/lang/RunnableCallable.java:68: warning - @return tag cannot be used in method with void return type.
[WARNING] /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/src/main/java/com/cloudera/hoop/FsPathParam.java:41: warning - @returns is an unknown tag.
[WARNING] /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/src/main/java/com/cloudera/hoop/Hoop.java:455: warning - @param argument "override," is not a parameter name.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1:dependencies (default) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-3:single (default-cli) @ hoop-server ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: maven/assembly-empty.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hoop WebApp 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.6:test (default-test) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1:war (default-war) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [hoop-webapp] in [/home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/target/hoop-webapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [52 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/target/hoop-webapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://github.com/cloudera/hoop/hoop-webapp
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[WARNING] The repository url 'http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2' is invalid - Repository 'datanucleus' will be blacklisted.
[WARNING] The repository url 'https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository' is invalid - Repository 'java.net' will be blacklisted.
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-3:single (default-cli) @ hoop-webapp ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: maven/assembly-empty.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hoop Client 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.6:test (default-test) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/target/hoop-client-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://github.com/cloudera/hoop/hoop-client
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ hoop-client >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ hoop-client <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] The goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc' has not be previously called for the project: 'com.cloudera.hoop:hoop-webapp:war:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'. Trying to invoke it...
[ERROR] MavenInvocationException: Error when invoking Maven, consult the invoker log file: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/target/invoker/maven-javadoc-plugin395037384.txt
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-webapp/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-docs/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-distro/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1:dependencies (default) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-3:single (default-cli) @ hoop-client ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: maven/assembly-hoop-client.xml
[INFO] Copying files to /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/target/hoop-client-lib
[WARNING] Assembly file: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-client/target/hoop-client-lib is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hoop Docs 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-docs/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pc/hoop/hoop-docs/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/pc/hoop/hoop-docs/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pc/hoop/hoop-docs/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.6:test (default-test) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/pc/hoop/hoop-docs/target/hoop-docs-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ hoop-docs ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.3.1
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://github.com/cloudera/hoop/hoop-docs
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-stylus-skin:jar:1.2 skin.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Hoop Project POM .................................. SUCCESS [7.496s]
[INFO] Hoop TestNG ....................................... SUCCESS [3:19.250s]
[INFO] Hoop Server ....................................... SUCCESS [4:11.171s]
[INFO] Hoop WebApp ....................................... SUCCESS [1:52.368s]
[INFO] Hoop Client ....................................... SUCCESS [4:30.761s]
[INFO] Hoop Docs ......................................... FAILURE [0.509s]
[INFO] Hoop Distro ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hoop Main ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14:02.178s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 05 17:45:37 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/724M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project hoop-docs: Error during site generation: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possib
```

Comment: The output information shows that failed to execute "maven-site-plugin", however, I found it here, ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.jar.

Comment: How about deleting `maven-site-plugin` folder in your local repo and retrying.  Maybe the site zip file is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks, Raghuram, I tried, but the problem was the same.

Comment: Thanks, Raghuram, I tried to delete the maven in my local repo and retry, it's working.